# Is it safe to use AbstractComposeView with TransitionManager?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

We started migration to Compose recently and migrated one `View` to `Composable` with `AbstractComposeView`.
The problem is that `TransitionManager` for some cases can trigger `addView` which is restricted in `AbstractComposeView` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/TransitionUtils.java#192

My question is how safe it is to use `TransitionManager` with `AbstractComposeView`?

Answer (score -2):

You should post this on twitter and tag #JetpackCompose, you'll probably get help quicker ~ and from the authors !